# How important is to have NAT for security for a Web application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, security, networking, nat

I am using AWS for a Django web application. I have configured a public subnet in which I have a web server. The security group associated with it only allows ports 443, 80, 22, 123. I have a private subnet in which I have a DB server. The security group associated with it only allows 5432 from the other security group.
So do I need to configure a NAT instance to which a public address is attached and only have private IP for the web server? How much does this sort of setup help with security or any other benefits?
Is this sort of setup a must?

Comment: NAT is not security. It is firewalls that provide security. Firewalls are often a convenient place to NAT, so some people think NAT is security, but it is not. Without a firewall, your NAT device could be compromised, and it has full access to the network behind the NAT, meaning that there is no security from NAT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A NAT is only needed if whatever is in your private subnet(s) needs to be able to reach the internet.

So unless there is a reason your database would need access to the internet, this configuration is fine.  If for example you occasionally need to apply patches to the db instance, you could simply create NAT instance on demand, update the routes, and run the update command. (If you're running Amazon Linux,you can create an S3 VPC endpoint and yum update will pull updates via that)

Comment: Thanks. When you say this configuration you mean to use NAT or to skip NAT? Also if the public IP of the web server is attached to the domain (Route 53), is that a security risk?

Comment: Having a single server exposed to the internet is not really scalable or reliable - you are much better off using autoscaling across multiple AZs behind a load balancer.  I don't know if your database needs to access the internet, or how often - that is up to you to decide.  If it doesn't, then you don't need a NAT.